# Simple JMeter Test does not work

Tags: java, testing, jsf-2, automated-tests, jmeter

we are trying to add a simple test using JMeter in a JSF Application. We followed the instructions in:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-adv-web-test-plan.html

It has a simple login page with user name and password and a submit button. You can see from the screenshots that we used a proxy. With the settings in the screenshot we are getting HTTP 500 Error. I am not sure if I placed the question in a right way.. Please ask if you need any clarification.

[image]

[image: Cookie Manager]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The error code is:
[image]
[image]

**EDIT**:
I think this is going to be the longest question of SO. But images are better than words sometimes. Anyway, what we have done is to sent the data that is equivalent to what we see in the firebug. But still getting 500 error. You can see in the attachments Tomcat log.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hm. As per "POST data" content from the last screen in your question empty value of javax.faces.ViewState is sent along with POST request. Try to adjust your RegEx / XML Extractor to get the viewstate. Look into this if not yet: http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/PerformanceTestingWithJMeter.

Comment: You have to activate "Regular Expression Extractor" component to get ${jsfViewState} evaluated.

Comment: do you know how to activate it?

Comment: do you mean the one under thread group? we have disabled the one under thread group, but the one under login.xhtml request is enabled.

Comment: If I got the right feeling, /EBS/login.xhtml is the login submit simulation. Then, there must be a "Regular Expression Extractor" in an HTTP Sampler before it to hold javax.faces.ViewState value.

Answer (score 5):

HTTP 5xx codes are related to server or application errors. Search log files first.

Your script don't need a "User Defined Variables" component because there's no variable expression that really need to be evaluated per thread/user.

The "Regular Expression Extractor" component suffice to extract the JSF ViewState value.
I suggest you to delete the last part of your expression, " />", and change the regular expression grouping (.+?) to (\w+?) 'cause it will evaluate to a few matches (probably only 2). Change the value of "Match No." field to 1 (no need to use random if all values matched are identical).

I didn't understand why you used both "XPath Extractor" and "Regular Expression Extractor" components to extract the same value. I prefer to use the last one when leading with html. XPath is better when treating with well-formed xml strings/files.

To capture a script from scratch, I suggest you to add a "HTTP Proxy Server" inside Workbench, configure it, start it, configure a browser to use this proxy and navigate those pages using the browser. This way you'll capture all requests made and request headers used by the browser you choose. After this, remove unnecessary requests and change query parameters, like javax.faces.ViewState, to the corresponding variables.

Consider using extractors (Pos-Processors) inside an HTTP Sampler prior to the one that will use the variable in Parameter Values. Ex.: if /EBS request comes first and /EBS/login.xhtml request have a javax.faces.ViewState parameter then, probably, /EBS response will contain a hidden input with the javax.faces.ViewState value.

This is a common make up of JSF application test scripts I use. Providing more information about the cause of the HTTP 500 error should clarify the way to a better solution.

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailed answer. We tried your recommendations but still getting HTTP 500 error. I added the latest screenshots, in case you may want to comment again.

Answer (score 5):

On the Regular Expression Extractor for jsfViewState, add `(?s)` to the start of the regular expression. So you have:

```
(?s)<input type="hidden" name="javax\.faces\.ViewState" id="javax\.faces\.ViewState" value="(.+?)" />
```

This allows the `(.+?)` to span line break characters.

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression extractor is in the wrong place. You cannot extract a value from the response to a request and then send it with the same request. The only way to achieve this is to use a time machine, but these don't exist yet and even if they did, it probably wouldn't work.

Typically you get a viewstate in the response to a GET and then you later need it in the POST of the same page. So, put the regular expression extractor as a *child* of the GET call where the login.xhtml page is first called (as a GET). If your recording does not include this GET call then either add it manually or examine the responses of previous calls before your login POST to find it, eg. maybe the GET homepage.xhtml (or similar) will include it.

Comment: thanks for your answer I gave up working with Jmeter for now, found another open source tool, which has good tutorials, trying it.